# How to apply self-defined function on the result of group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to group by the data by some column then replace NA with most recent observation. Is there any way to apply a function other than aggregation function to the result of group_by?

Here is the two sample implemented with ddply:

1:

```
dt<-data.table(A=rep(c(1:3),2), B=c(1,2,NA,NA,2,5),C=c(9,NA,2,8,NA,4)
ddply(dt,"A",function(x){na.locf(x, na.rm = FALSE,fromLast=FALSE)})
```

2:

```
ddply(dt,"A",function(x){
 if (x[1,"A"]>2){
  x[,2:3]*1
 } else {
  x[,2:3]*(-1)
}

})
```

I don't know how to replicate it with groug_by which should be faster than ddply. By the way, is there any NA replacement function quicker than na.locf?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you would do this with `dplyr`

```
dt %>%
   group_by(A) %>%
   mutate_each(funs(na.locf(., na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = FALSE)))
```

But if you already using `data.table`, why not just use it?

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, na.locf, na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = FALSE), by = A]
```

You could also update the data table by reference using `:=` operator as in

```
dt[, names(dt)[-1] := lapply(.SD, na.locf, na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = FALSE), A]
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. If we use by in the data.table, can we do the if-else condition? In the example, if A==1, calculate mean else run standard deviation. @David Arenburg